# Possible to configure maven-javadoc-plugin NOT to include the generation date?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I'm using the `maven-javadoc-plugin` to rebuild Javadocs every time I build my project.  These are built to the Maven project's `/docs` directory so the API documentation can be served up as a Github Pages site.  One annoyance is that every time the project is re-built (e.g., `mvn clean install`), the HTML pages are updated by Javadoc with the generation date, for example lines 5 and 8 below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- NewPage -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Generated by javadoc (13.0.2) on Fri May 29 15:18:24 EDT 2020 -->
<title>Uses of Class [my class] ([project] [version] API)</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="dc.created" content="2020-05-29">
```

That means for virtually every change no matter how minor, I'm obligated to update the entire `/docs` directory in version control.  This could make it harder for others to navigate the git history as all these javadoc changes swamp the real changes to code.

**Is there a way to suppress the inclusion of generation dates, so that the only changed Javadoc files will be the ones with actual changes to content?**

Comment: I realize that an alternative would be to perhaps use a CI tool to build the javadocs and commit them in their own separate commits, but in this question I'm specifically looking for a way to configure maven-javadoc-plugin to not include the generation date in every file.

Comment: Changing the content of a directory which is under version control is a bad idea. If you build release usually you should build the javadocs then and after released to central you can use services like javadoc.io ...